# How to delete data properly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, crud

This is my delete button

```
              <!-- Hapus Data -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-     target="#exampleModal">
                Hapus
              </button>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data? </h5>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                      <a href="/deletedata/{{$row->id_pegawai}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ya</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I try to make CRUD using laravel. When i try to delete the third data, but the deleted data is first data. So i deleted data not what i want to delete

this is my controller

```
public function deletedata($id_pegawai){

        $post = Employee::where('id_pegawai',$id_pegawai)->first();
        if ($post != null) {
            $post->delete();
            return redirect('pegawai')->with('success', 'Data berhasil dihapus!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent provides multiple ways to do it. Here are some examples:

1 - Using a model instance

```php
$employee = Employee::find($id);
$employee->delete();
```

2 - Delete using a where statement

```php
Employee::where('column', $value)->delete();
```

This is useful in a situation where you have to delete one or more rows, not necessarily knowing their primary keys (but it could be used as well).

3 - Using `destroy` method

```php
Employee::destroy($id);
```

This will also remove many rows at once, if you pass them like

```php
Employee::destroy($id1, $id2, $id3 /* and so on...*/);
```

or

```php
Employee::destroy(collect([$id1, $id2, $id3]));
```

Font: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#deleting-models

Comment: Uh where did i should place and what should i replace? I'm still very new to Laravel. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

set the route up inside **routes/web.php** like

```
Route::post('/deletedata/{employeeid}', [EmployeeController::class, 'deletedata')->name('employee.delete');
```

access the route like in

```
href="{{route('employee.delete', $row->id)}}"
```

Important notice: When dealing with sensitive data, use a form with hidden inputs. [Read more here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#csrf-field) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#method-field)

Answer (score 0):

> blade form

```
<form action="{{ route('deletedata', [$row->id_pegawai]) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<button type="submit"> DELETE </button>
</form>
```

> web route

```
Route::delete('/deletedata/{userId}', [EmployeeController::class, 'destroy')->name('deletedata');
```

> EmployeeController

```
public function destroy(Employee $userId)
{
   $userId->delete();
   return "user deleted";
}
```